# Single call to get near by places via Facebook SDK and Google Places API

Tags: android, facebook, google-places-api

I want to implement a single call method for getting near by places from Facebook SDK and Google Places API.

I have researched that Facebook SDK uses AsyncTask inside their RequestAsyncTask method and there is no other way to work with Facebook API(use only their AsyncTask). Other situation in Google Places API, you just need to know the url and implement your own AsyncTask,non UI thread or service to send request in background.

So, I would like to know what the best practise in this situation to implement the single call of both APIs if we have use restrictions in Facebook SDK.

I have some thoughts how to do it but I am not sure they are correct:

- probably, I can implement my own AsyncTask where I will call Facebook RequestAsyncTask method and simple HTTP request to Google Places API(i.e. AsyncTask inside AsyncTask)
- probably, I can implement my own Service where I will call Facebook RequestAsyncTask method and simple HTTP request to Google Places API(i.e. AsyncTask inside Service). However, as I know AsyncTask demands Activity context which Service can be not have in one moment(screen rotate or close app) that will cause app crashes
- probably, I can override the existing Facebook RequestAsyncTask method, which will be trigger Google Places API, when Facebook Request starts to execute

That is all thoughts which I have. May be, there is no good decision from my list and you have your own vision how to do it better in this case. Could you, please, help me in this question and if it will not complicate you could you also present some simple examples how to implement this situation better?

Comment: And the results from both requests, should they be aggregated then? How do you want to prensent the results to the Users?

Comment: For users result will be look like a combined response from bath API, for developer results will be serialized in different objects - Facebook response will be serialized to Graph object by Facebook design and Google response to special Google object. I also plan to create one main object which will have reference to main facebook and Google objects.

Comment: Well, I don't really think it makes sense to implement this on the client/device side. You should think about encapsulating this into a service you're hosting, which is then requested by the devices by passing lat and lng parameters.

Comment: I agree, in ideal it should be on server side, but I would like to know could I do it somehow on client side as less pain as it only possible or client side will be TOO overloaded in comparison with implemented it on server side in any case? That is to say I just need to know if it will be quite easy and not so painful implement it on client side then it is cool. If it is too difficult, too overloaded and absolutely wrong decision in any sense which will lead to additional difficulties then ok I will start to think to server way.

Comment: Personally, I think it's a bad decision to do this on the client side (data to be transferred, computing of results etc.), but in the end it's your call.

Comment: OK, thank you for your opinion, I will take it to my attention and most likely I will try to stand up server side for my purposes. However, I just clarify on future, how you will do this implmenetation if your decision will be to do all of this on client side(forget about performace between client and server implementation, just tech decision). I`m interesting in that point, how you will combine native Facebook AsyncTask with calling request to Googple Places API - you will put Facebook AsyncTask inside another AsyncTask or Service or some another way to do a single call to both APIs?

Comment: There's NO way of calling both APIs at once!

Comment: I have researched the situation where I need single API which will trigger another social APIs(http://docs.oneall.com/api/, http://gnip.com/). I have found a lot of different services who handle it but their opportunities allow you to post, repost, receive list of friends, add to friends only and that`s all. No full API, for example, to Graph API or to Google Places. It covers only social communation tasks - no place or whatever search. May be, you knows such a services who provide full APIs to social networks? It`s preffered It will be free for use.

Comment: May be, someone knows such an All in one API for free and with almost full realized social APIs. I have found only All in API for free where you can only post, repost, add to friend, share something but no searching at all. And found one more All in One API not for free where  you can order what kind of functional I need for my purposes.